# I want to configure Apache CXF Oauth2 in my web-services

Tags: oauth-2.0, cxf

From last since 2 week i am trying to implement Oauth2 functionality in my api.
http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-oauth2.html
I know how Oauth2 is working. but how to configured it in my api that i am not able to under stand

Comment: Do you want to implement OAuth server or just OAuth client auhorization?

Comment: OAuth client auhorization